# Why any $(n -1)$-face of a $n$-simplex is the face of exactly one other $n$-simplex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex

[image]

I think it's possible to be contained in odd numbers of other $n$-simplexes, for example we may identify the edges of two cube's boundaries.

Comment: Your 'edges of two cube's boundaries' would be $n-2$ simplexes, which is not what your textbook excerpt is talking about.

Comment: @Spencer, here I don't assume the cubes have interiors, i.e. no 3-simplexes, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: But the problem _states_ the cubes have interiors. $n-$simplexes sharing faces  in an $n-$ complex triangulating an $n- $manifold.

Comment: @Spencer, so the problem is my object is not a 2-manifold, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem with your example case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although what you say is possible in a general simplicial complex, it is not possible in a simplicial complex which is a triangulation of an $n$-manifold.

To see why, use local homology calculations.

First, for any $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ and for any point $x \in M$, the $n$-dimensional local relative homology group $H_n(M,M-x;\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

However, for any $n$-dimensional simplicial complex $X$, and for any $n-1$ dimensional simplex $\sigma$ which is a face of exactly $k$ simplices of dimension $n$, and for every point $x$ in the interior of $\sigma$, the group $H_n(X,X-x;\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$.

Putting these together, if $X$ is an $n$-manifold then $k-1=1$ so $k=2$.

On an intuitive level, what this is saying is that a $n-1$ dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ locally separates into two pieces, and that's what's happening locally near a point in the interior of an $n-1$ simplex in an $n$-manifold.

Comment: But it seems you can also apply the same proof to the general simplicial complex, in other words, how is this proof related to the a simplicial complex which is a triangulation of an $n$-manifold?

Comment: For a general simplicial complex, $H_n(X,X-x;\mathbb{Z})$ need not be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, as it must for an $n$-manifold.